# How to Export HTML Page to a PDF File In Banana Dashboard

Tags: solr, html2canvas, pdfmake, lucidworks, banana

I am trying to generate a PDF file out of the banana dashboard.

I have made the following changes to the files:

1. Added a div id to the main div in index.html file

`<div ng-view id="myDiv"></div>`

2. Added two js files necessary for PDF generation into `vendor` folder of banana application

`html2canvas.js`
`pdfmake.js`

3. Updated the `require.config.js` file to point to these two new js files as below:

   `html2canvas:              ../vendor/html2canvas,`

   `pdfmake:                  ../vendor/pdfmake`
4. Updated the `dashLoader.html` file to include another item in the showdown list as '`Export to PDF`'

`<li ng-show="dashboard.current.loader.save_local">
<a href="" alt="Export to File" title="Export to PDF" class="link" ng-click="dashboard.to_pdf()">
<i class="icon-download"></i> Export to PDF</a>
<tip>Export layout and data to PDF file</tip>
</li>`

5. Finally updated the `dashboard.js` file as below:

   `this.to_pdf = function () {
               var inclusions = document.getElementById('myDiv');
               console.log(inclusions);
               html2canvas(inclusions).then(function(canvas) {//this line is throwing error as html2canvas is not defined
               inclusions.appendChild(canvas);
               data_1 = canvas.toDataURL();
               resolve(data_1);
               console.log(inclusions);
           }); 
               return true;
           };`

But when I click on the `Export to PDF` option I get the error `“Error: html2canvas is not defined”`. Please refer the screenshot attached.

[image: banana export to PDF error]

Any help on where I am going wrong would be very thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standalone Hello World html2canvas html program helped to fix this. The correct way to invoke html2canvas and then pdfmake (or any other pdf generation library) is as below:

```
  html2canvas(document.getElementById('divId')).then(
    canvas =>{
    var data =canvas.toDataURL();
    var docDefiniton ={
     content:[{
      image:data,
      width:500
     }]
    };
    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
    }
);
```